# Cannot install bazel on Ubuntu 20.04 - invalid EXPKEYSIG

Tags: ubuntu, bazel, ubuntu-20.04

I was following the instructions on https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/install-ubuntu.html#install-with-installer-ubuntu

and trying to install bazel on Ubuntu.

When I run step 2:
`sudo apt update && sudo apt install bazel`

I get:

```
Get:1 https://storage.googleapis.com/bazel-apt stable InRelease [2,256 B]
Hit:2 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                                         
Hit:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                            
Hit:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease                    
Err:1 https://storage.googleapis.com/bazel-apt stable InRelease
  The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG 3D5919B448457EE0 Bazel Developer (Bazel APT repository key) <bazel-dev@googlegroups.com>
Hit:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease                  
Hit:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease                     
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: https://storage.googleapis.com/bazel-apt stable InRelease: The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG 3D5919B448457EE0 Bazel Developer (Bazel APT repository key) <bazel-dev@googlegroups.com>
E: The repository 'https://storage.googleapis.com/bazel-apt stable InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Tracking in https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/11470

Answer (score 20):

The Bazel Ubuntu PPA key has expired.

From https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/11470#issuecomment-633205152:

> You may have to manually update your apt keyring with the new key:
>
> ```
> $ curl https://bazel.build/bazel-release.pub.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
> $ sudo apt-get update
> ```

Answer (score 7):

Try to install Bazel by using Bazelisk as follows:

1. `cd ~`
2. `wget https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazelisk/releases/download/v1.6.1/bazelisk-linux-amd64`
3. `chmod +x bazelisk-linux-amd64`
4. `sudo ln -s ~/bazelisk-linux-amd64 /usr/bin/bazel`
5. to test run: `bazel version`

Comment: bazel: command not found

Comment: It's not meant to replace `bazel`, it's just a `bazel` version installer. Symlinking it to `/usr/bin/bazel` is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the key expired two years ago in 2020 and then was extended to May 2022.
I fixed the problem with the installation instructions for ubuntu [1](https://bazel.build/install/ubuntu#install-on-ubuntu)

Which meant

```
sudo apt install apt-transport-https curl gnupg
curl -fsSL https://bazel.build/bazel-release.pub.gpg | gpg --dearmor >bazel-archive-keyring.gpg
sudo mv bazel-archive-keyring.gpg /usr/share/keyrings
echo "deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/bazel-archive-keyring.gpg] https://storage.googleapis.com/bazel-apt stable jdk1.8" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/bazel.list
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it worked for me

```bash
sudo apt install curl gnupg
curl -fsSL https://bazel.build/bazel-release.pub.gpg | gpg --dearmor > bazel.gpg
sudo mv bazel.gpg /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/
echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://storage.googleapis.com/bazel-apt stable jdk1.8" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/bazel.list
sudo apt update && sudo apt install bazel
sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade
bazel --version
```

Comment: I had to change ```sudo apt update && sudo apt install bazel``` by  ```sudo apt update && sudo apt install bazel-6.2.1``` and it worked! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Bazel team updated the gpg public key, but due to network caching https://bazel.build/bazel-release.pub.gpg may still return the old key,

Please use the following command to update the public key on your local machine:

```
curl -fsSL https://storage.googleapis.com/www.bazel.build/bazel-release.pub.gpg | gpg --dearmor >bazel-archive-keyring.gpg
mv bazel-archive-keyring.gpg /usr/share/keyrings/
```

Reference : https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/15558#issuecomment-1136150886