# The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 3D5919B448457EE0

Tags: ubuntu, bazel

> Err:3 https://storage.googleapis.com/bazel-apt stable InRelease
> The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 3D5919B448457EE0

I don't find bazel on my machine and when i do - sudo apt update - i face the above error.

Tried Steps
https://groups.google.com/g/bazel-dev/c/HypiWo1Fymo
[Cannot install bazel on Ubuntu 20.04 - invalid EXPKEYSIG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61982500/cannot-install-bazel-on-ubuntu-20-04-invalid-expkeysig)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
curl -fsSL https://storage.googleapis.com/www.bazel.build/bazel-release.pub.gpg | gpg --dearmor >bazel-archive-keyring.gpg
mv bazel-archive-keyring.gpg /usr/share/keyrings/
```

to update the gpg public key